# Urge Her Against Him

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, word-usage

For this:

> [google book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Z6DULu31h7UC&pg=PT221&dq=%22urged+her+against%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s-MyUfqSKYjoigKeoID4Dg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA)
>   "With one hand on the small of her back, and another just a bit lower, ***he urged her against him*** again. The woman was melting his resolve and calling into question his honorable intentions."

What is "urge her against him"?  Dictionaries don't say anything about "urge against".

Comment: What kind of crap are you reading?? ;-)

Comment: @Jim I apologize for the adult-nature of the example.  It's just that I am confused by the usage.

Answer (score 1):

Each word has its own meaning.

"Against" means "in contact with" ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/against))

"Urge" has several meanings, almost all of which work:

> 1. to push or force along; impel with force or vigor: to urge the cause along.
> 2. to drive with incitement to speed or effort: to urge dogs on with shouts.
> 3. to press, push, or hasten (the course, activities, etc.): to urge one's escape.
> 4. to impel, constrain, or move to some action: urged by necessity.
> 5. to endeavor to induce or persuade, as by entreaties; entreat or exhort earnestly: to urge a person to greater caution. ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/urge?s=t))

Comment: Does that mean "He ordered/threatened the hostages against the wall" is good English?